# Iterate list of element to select from hidden list using selenium webdriver

Tags: select, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've to select an year from the list were in HTML response is having two div tags. click on first div, year list will be open then choose an year from the hidden portion of

tag.

[image]

And the response for the HTML div tags are placed below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi based on your markup you can try getting all elements in the  tag and check their contents for text match(date) alternatively an Xpath.

Here's an idea on how to go about implementing the iteration and scrolling
Hope this helps

```
  List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.tagName("ul"));

    for(WebElement option: options){

        if(option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")){

            option.click();
                    }

        else{
            //TODO Scroll select or User Action

        }

    }
```